# Export data of a function of 3 variables

Tags: export, list-manipulation, dataset

I have a function like this

```
 ntrK[x_, k_, \[Psi]_, \[Delta]_] := 
     1 + (E^(-(x^2/(2 \[Delta]^2))) x^2 \[Psi])/\[Delta]^4 - (
      E^(-(x^2/(
        2 \[Delta]^2))) \[Psi])/\[Delta]^2 - (0.19947114020071635` Gamma[
          1 + k] ((
           Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Gamma[-(3/2) + k])/((1/(-3 + 2 k))^(3/2)
             Gamma[k]) - 
           8 Sqrt[E^(-(x^2/(2 \[Delta]^2))) \[Psi]]
             Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, k, 3/2, (
             2 E^(-(x^2/(2 \[Delta]^2))) \[Psi])/(
             3 - 2 k)]))/(k Sqrt[-3 + 2 k] Gamma[-0.5` + k])
```

I need to integrate this funciton with respect to x. As the analytical way is not working out I went to go for numerical integration using NIntegrate.

```
Table[NIntegrate[ntrK[x, 3, \[Psi], \[Delta]], {x, -500., 500.}, 
       AccuracyGoal -> 15, MaxRecursion -> 10]/1000, {\[Psi], 1, 10, 
      1}, {\[Delta], 20, 50, 01}]
```

Here I specified the value of k as three.I would like to export a .dat file that contains the integrated value for k psi and various delta. That is for a k value,I have a list of psi and for each psi I have a List of delta. The .dat file should look like:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `k`, `psi`, `delta`, and `iv` are variables containing the lists of data, then:

```
array = Flatten[#] & /@ {{"k", k}, {"psi", psi}, {"delta", delta}, {"integratedValue", iv}}

Export[file, Transpose[array], "CSV"]
```

CSV stands for comma-separated values, and is a very useful and widely supported format for exporting tables that don't have commas in them.

---

For constructing the lists (`k`, `psi`, `delta`, `iv`), I suggest simply storing the parameters while constructing the integration value table and then transforming the array so that they can be assigned directly:

```
dat = Table[
    {k, ψ, δ, NIntegrate[ntrK[x, 3, ψ, δ], {x, -500., 500.}, 
        AccuracyGoal -> 15, MaxRecursion -> 10]/1000},
    {k, 2, 3, 1}, {ψ, 1, 3, 1}, {δ, 2, 5, 1}];
{k, psi, delta, iv} = Transpose@Flatten[dat, 2]
```

Comment: Sir, here I need to mention two things, If you see the program, I have specified the value of k. here the problem is all the time I need to change the value of k and give run again. So I want to automatize it . Such that a single run will make a data file of format .dat shown in the picture. Also, the integrated value is not a variable, it is the output of the integration that we perform inside the table. Hence for each value of psi and k We will get a curve between integrated value and delta.

Comment: @HariKrishnan That doesn't mean you can't or shouldn't store the integration value in a variable for the sake of writing it into an array. It's just a matter of deciding how you want to create the data tables. I'll include that in an edit.

Comment: Thank you sir.. It worksss